# Is there a way to create a conditional foreign key depending on a field's value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to create a table like

```
 CREATE TABLE SearchUser(
  SearchID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UserID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserId),
  [scan_id] NVARCHAR(8),
  [scan_type] NVARCHAR(3),
  [tokens_left] INT);
```

where depending on scan_type value, I would like to be able to utilize different foreign keys
 i.e.

if [scan_type] = 'ORG'
I would like [scan_id] to be a foreign key to Org(scan_id)

if [scan_type] = 'PER'
I would like [scan_id] to be a foreign key to Per(scan_id)

Comment: No, this is not directly possible, although there might be other ways to do what you want.

Comment: Personally, it sounds like you have a design flaw, and the `Org` and `Per` should be a single table, with a column `scan_type` (and then `scan_type` isn't stored in the table `SearchUser`).

Comment: Unfortunately Org and Per cannot be merged as they're created during JSON de-serialization from API call results

Comment: If the tables are created (and therefore dropped) you won't be able to use them as a foreign key candidate then. (Well you could, but your `DROP` will fail.)

Comment: Sounds to me like `Org` and `Per` should have a foreign key to `SearchID` if they need to be related to this table here; a Search will relate to either an Org or a Per, or both, or neither

Comment: Your problem is widely discussed with the name of "Polymorphic associations". You will find many things to read about it and some way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server it's impossible to create a dynamic foreign key but, you can implement table inheritance, which solves your problem e.g.:

> CREATE TABLE BaseScan(
> Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
> SharedProperties....); 
>   CREATE TABLE OrgScan(
>       Id INT...,
>       BaseScanId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BaseScan(Id));
>   
>   CREATE TABLE dbo.PerScan(
>       Id INT...,
>       BaseScanId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BaseScan(Id));

This way you'll be able to reference BaseScan.Id in SearchUser and then join the data you need depending on 'scan-type' value.

Comment: OrgScan = Organization Scan (contains OrgName Location e.t.c.). PerScan = Person Scan (contains FirtName, LastName e.t.c.) so the properties differ; the only field they (might) share is Scan_Id

Answer (score 0):

As other devs mention, it is not possible directly in nutshell. But there is still hope if you want to implement the same.

You can apply check constraint on column. You can create function for check and call it for check constraint like below.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_CheckFunction CHECK ( dbo.CheckFunction() = 1 );
```

In function you can write your logic accordingly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckFunction ()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN ( SELECT 1 );
END;
```